# Excecuting untill get a good result

Tags: python

I am wondering is it possible to create a function which will be executing a function untill I will enter a correct value?

I created my function for one particular function. I would like to create a function for any function where I could put a function as argument.

````
def execute_untill_good_result():
    while True:
        try:
            return get_number_from_range('Enter value from range <100, 999>.', 100, 999)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)```
````

Answer (score 0):

accept the function as an argument like this:

```
def execute_until_good_result(func, *args, **kwargs):
    while True:
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

and use like this:

```
result = execute_until_good_result(get_number_from_range, 'Enter value from range <100, 999>.', 100, 999)
```